# Reverse Proxy Showing Ubuntu Default Screen

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-proxy

I've been running a httpd CentOS7 reverse proxy for around a year now and decided to upgrade my servers to Ubuntu with Apache2 as CentOS is EOL, but now that I've set up my reverse proxies it's just showing the default apache2 page.

I have enabled mod_proxy for apache2 and here's my code in apache2.conf

```
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
    Options None
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://95.xxx.xxx.xxx/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://95.xxx.xxx.xxx/"

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This previous worked on CentOS and I have read a few tutorials to make sure there's no major differences in code in which I haven't found any, any idea why this might be happening ?

apach2ctl -S output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server vps3294-ejzmx.hosting.provider (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost vps3294-ejzmx.hosting.provider (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:234)
                 alias example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```